How to approach on debugging test failure on Circle Ci?
A few of my tests are failing only on Circle Ci but they are running on Local. I don't know the root cause of this:
These are things I have tried so far:

Added conditional wait for waiting until an element on the page is visible

Used page.waitForLoadState(LoadState.NetworkIdle), page.waitForLoadState(page.waitForLoadState(LoadState.DOMLoaded))

Removed the thread-count to 1 assuming if there was any thread-sync issue


@BeforeMethod
public void navigate() {
navigate("/abc");
----
}
Navigate function is defined in the Base class as
public void navigate(String relativeUrl) {
try { // Timeout extra wait for the navigation to happen smoothly
page.navigate(config.getUrl() + relativeUrl, new Page.NavigateOptions().setTimeout(100000));
page.waitForLoadState(LoadState.NETWORKIDLE);
page.waitForLoadState(LoadState.DOMCONTENTLOADED);
    }

Any help would be appreciated
Tests are passing in the local but failing on Circle Ci
I increased the navigation time and also added a wait for the load state
but still getting the following error
``Navigation Timeout: Error {
message='Timeout 100000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
navigating to "url/abc", waiting until "load"
